# In the Jquery .addClass() and .removeClass() functions problem of remembering if previous

Tags: jquery

I have a problem that by clicking on the list group id_amici I send the id from the database and insert the addClass() the problem that by clicking again I send the new id and I cannot use the .removeClass() function to remove the previous id, how can I do it? .. Thank you

```
----- HTML PHP --------

$query_logo ="SELECT `ph_banner` FROM `fli_foto_utente` WHERE `id-utente`= '" . $id_utente . "'";
  $rs_logo = mysql_query ($query_logo, $conn);
  $check_foto = false;
  while( $rows_logo = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_logo) ) {
    if ( $rows_logo['ph_banner'] == 'logo' ) {
      $check_foto = true;
    }
  }
  $img_user = "assets/img/user.png";

  if ( $check_foto ) {
    $img_user = "assets/upload/foto_utente/id_ph_" . $id_utente . "/" . $rows_logo['foto-utente'];      
  } else {
    switch ( $rows_utente['genere'] ) {
      case 'maschile':
        $img_user = "assets/img/man.png";
        break;
      case 'femminile':
        $img_user = "assets/img/girl.png";
        break;
      case 'altro':
      default:
        $img_user = "assets/img/user.png";
        break; 
    }
  }

  ?>

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="ev-chat_<?php echo $rows_amici['amici_id']; ?>" data-id_amici="<?php echo $rows_amici['amici_id']; ?>">          
           <span class="chat-img"> <img src="<?php echo $img_user; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid" ></span> <?php echo $nomeandcogn; ?>
           
        </a>
        
  <?php 
}


----- Jquery ------


$('[id*="ev-chat_"]').click(function() {

      var clickCount = 0;

      var id_amici = $(this).data("id_amici");      
      
      $('#ev-chat_' + idamici).removeClass("active-plus");      

      clickCount++;

      if (clickCount != String(1)) {
        $('#ev-chat_' + id_amici).prev().removeClass('active-plus');

      }else if (clickCount == String(1)){

        $('#ev-chat_' + id_amici).addClass('active-plus');
      }

 });
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear, but possibly: `$(".active-plus").removeClass('active-plus')` before you  add to the current.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#container .list-group-item").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var clickCount = $this.data('click_count') || 0;

    $this.removeClass("active-plus");      

    clickCount++;

    if (clickCount == 1){
      $this.addClass('active-plus');
    } else {
      $this.prev().removeClass('active-plus');
    }
    
     $this.data('click_count', clickCount);
 });
 
 $("#radio .list-group-item").click(function() {
    $("#radio .list-group-item").removeClass("active-plus");      
    $(this).addClass("active-plus");
 });
```

```css
.active-plus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  margin:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="ev-chat_123" data-id_amici="123">         
    <span class="chat-img"> 
      <img src="" alt="" class="img-fluid" >
    </span> 
    $nomeandcogn
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="ev-chat_456" data-id_amici="456">         
    <span class="chat-img"> 
      <img src="" alt="" class="img-fluid" >
    </span> 
    $nomeandcogn
  </a>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="radio">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="ev-chat_123" data-id_amici="123">         
    <span class="chat-img"> 
      <img src="" alt="" class="img-fluid" >
    </span> 
    Radio1
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="ev-chat_456" data-id_amici="456">         
    <span class="chat-img"> 
      <img src="" alt="" class="img-fluid" >
    </span> 
    Radio2
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="ev-chat_456" data-id_amici="456">         
    <span class="chat-img"> 
      <img src="" alt="" class="img-fluid" >
    </span> 
    Radio3
  </a>
</div>
```

The `clickCount` is always `1`.

`$('#ev-chat_' + idamici).removeClass("active-plus");` variable `idamici` without `_`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks I solved with the simplest form the one you suggested with #radio ...... I was getting complicated with the numeric IDs when I could solve more simply as you said,

Thanks again